# Find the longest path to the first vertex of graph defined by Markov chain

Tags: graph, markov-chains

I need to define a Markov chain and plot a graph of it with the following properties:

- There are 4 vertices
- Each vertex has equal probability to jump to any other vertex (0.25)
- The vertex S<sub>1</sub> is the starting vertex

> The Image below is what I think the graph should look like, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

[image: Graph]

Does the Markov chain look like this?

And if it does:

> What is the shortest path (counting the edges) to S<sub>1</sub>?

That should be the `1` since there is an edge that returns to S<sub>1</sub>.

> What is the longest path (counting the edges) to S<sub>1</sub>?

If we assume we go through each vertex only twice (one time from the previous vertex, and one time from the loop), then that should be `7`.

But what about the probabilities?

Comment: Yes. Zero, you're already there. What about them?

Comment: We have 1/4 probability to jump from S2->S3->S4. Can we just assume that we don't repeat any jumps, before reaching S1 again? Nowhere in my textbook is it said how I should go about finding the longest path. So I really don't know how to calculate it. How do I take the probabilities into account?

Comment: As with many probability puzzles, asking the right question is the hardest part. If you start at S2, the prob of S2->S3 is 1/4, and the prob of S2->S3->S4 is 1/16. Do you want to know the prob that the traveler will visit all other vertices without revisiting a vertex? Or that he will do that and then return to the starting vertex on the next step?

Comment: Yes, and that is a non-English textbook, so I'm trying to translate as best as I can. The question reads: "Find the longest path for re-entering S1". Or as I understand it, how many max. vertices do I have to visit before returning to S1, based on the probabilities?

Comment: The longest path is four steps. The probability that the traveler will take such a path is (3/4)(2/4)(1/4)(1/4)=3/128.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why won't the traveler, for example go through a loop or visit a vertex twice? And also, the minimal path for re-entering S1 is `1` or `0`?

Add that as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to find the probability that the traveler will walk a Hamiltonian cycle (a path that visits every node exactly once and then returns to the starting node):

Call the starting node S1, and the traveler T. The first step T takes must be to some *other* node, not to S1. Three such nodes are available. The prob of that is 3/4.

Having reached that node, call it S2, T must then proceed to a new node, not S1 and not S2, but one of the remaining two. The prob of that is 2/4.

Having completed that step to the node we'll call S3, T has only one node left to visit, call it S4. Moving to S1, S2 or S3 means failure. Moving to S4 has prob 1/4.

Having made it to S4, T's next move must be back to S1 and nowhere else. Th prob of this is 1/4.

Total probability: (3/4)(2/4)(1/4)(1/4) = 3/128.